# Can we include php file in html file?

Tags: php, html

How can we include a php file into a html file?

I know we can do this with:

```
  <AddType application/x-httpd-php .html>
```

but I don't have access to the server. Any other solution which I can include in my website folder or file?

Comment: @air: What do you mean by 'include'? As in like server-side include?

Comment: Perhaps you can ask your host if they will add that line? It's a long shot but worth it.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just rename the file to end in PHP? That would be the simplest way to do this.

Comment: While I think this is the right answer, he may not want to rename a bunch of links to point to foo.php instead of foo.html.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to your website folder, you could create a `.htaccess` file that includes:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</IfModule>
```

You could alternatively try:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: yes i have access to my website folder... what name should i give to file... and i am on windows2003 server does this work for windows 2003 server ?

Comment: No, this is for Apache. It's useful to state such things in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the code looks like that you want to include, and if you **really** have no other choice like the ones presented by Druid, you can use one of the following less-than-perfect embedding solutions:

- An IFRAME with frameborder="0" pointing to the PHP script (Downside: dynamic resizing according to output size is possible only with JavaScript
- An AJAX Snippet that loads the PHP file onLoad and injects the output into a DIV of your choice
- A  tag pointing to the PHP file. The PHP file must then issue JavaScript commands like "document.write()".

The IFRAME is the most fail-safe in the event the client has no JavaScript. The AJAX Snippet is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is not renaming it to `.php`.
It is renaming to `.phtml` ;)

.phtml is the official file type for crossover files containing `PHP` and `HTML` code.

Comment: uhm, what? php will always contain html code, that's what is was developed for

Comment: @knittl: Yes, that is what PHP *was* developed for. But now it is used in many different areas. Some companies I know use it in backend development to solve no html / web related business problems whatsoever.