# PHP HTML Embed PHP Tags within a .HTML Document Is This Possible?

Tags: php, html

Embedding HTML within .PHP files is one of the primary functionalities of PHP, but is it possible to do it the other way round?

I mean, embedding PHP tags,  , within a .HTML document??
Is this sort of coding possible?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581765/can-we-include-php-file-in-html-file

Comment: What about if wampserver is the current, offline server?
Is there a similar file to edit?

Comment: With Wampserver and apache on Windows, find file httpd.conf and add line 
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html 

You can now mix PHP tags within your .HTML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file and HTML files will be handled like PHP files allowing you put PHP in HTML files.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Some [more information](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm) on it here

Answer (score 1):

If you configure your server properly you can put php code in almost any kind of file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache, just add this line in the httpd.conf file

"AddType application/x-httpd-php .html"

Now you can embed php tags in .html files and they will be parsed correctly